# only first element in jquery each loop getting updated

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am just trying to do an each loop on elements containing the class front but only first element is getting updated for some reason please help. May be it is a silly mistake but i am unable to find it.

**jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/sVTCK/7/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="front"></div>
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
function setSlide(rows, dimension) {
    var topPos = 0;
    var leftPos = 0;
    $(".front").each(function(i, e) {
        topPos++;
        if (i % rows === 0) {
            topPos = 0;
            leftPos++;
        }
        var position = topPos * dimension + " " + (leftPos - 1) * dimension;
        e.style.backgroundPosition = position;  
        e.innerHTML =  e.style.backgroundPosition;
    });
}
setSlide(3,200);
```

**css:**

```
.front{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;    
    background:url(some image);
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left
}

.wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:610px;    
}
```

Comment: do you want only add the dimension at squares?

Comment: That would be image in end product

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function setSlide(rows, dimension) {
    var topPos = 0;
    var leftPos = 0;
    $(".front").each(function(i, e) {
        topPos++;
        if (i % rows === 0) {
            topPos = 0;
            leftPos++;
        }
        var position = topPos * dimension + 'px ' + (leftPos - 1) * dimension +'px';
        e.style.backgroundPosition = position;  
        e.innerHTML =  e.style.backgroundPosition;
    });
}
setSlide(3,200);
```

**[THE WORKING DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/sVTCK/14/)**

Comment: To explain, positions (and lengths in general) need units. Unless they're zero, which is why your first element was working.

Answer (score 1):

ok I've refractored the javascript stlightly into jquery since your using it and moved from the vanilla javascript:

```
function setSlide(rows, dimension) {
    var topPos = 0;
    var leftPos = 0;
    var front = $('.front');
    $.each(front, function(index, val) {
        topPos++;
        if (index % rows === 0) {
            topPos = 0;
            leftPos++;
        }
        var position = topPos * dimension + "px, " + (leftPos - 1) * dimension + 'px';
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', position);
        $(this).append(position);
    });
}
setSlide(3,200);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sVTCK/18/

If you can tell us what your trying to do with the if statement it would help to add the background-position...
You should be reallying on jQuery if you have it in page since it'll be quicker and you should also be caching your variables

Comment: You are wrong. see inspect element only first element is getting updated. Above answer is the correct one. I forgot "px"

Comment: read what i said.... I mentioned the if statement and the background position. It's also rather arrognat of you just to brush of someones effort and time taken. Try to be a little more humble when asking for help